# ¿Como incluyo otros archivos .py con cx_freeze si estoy usando rutas absolutas?

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo una pequeña GUI construida con `tkinter` que quiero compilar con cx_freeze a un ejecutable .exe.

Encontré hace un tiempo que para generar la GUI, al compilador le tendría que incluir los DLLs (es para Windows) de `tkinter`. Ahora, estos DLLs están en una ruta completamente distinta a mi entorno de trabajo para esta GUI (ver `setup.py` líneas abajo), por lo que tengo que usar una ruta **absoluta**. De la misma manera, incluyo dos archivos que están en la misma carpeta (un ícono y un txt).

El problema nace de que, si quiero añadir un archivo mediante su ruta **(sea relativa o absoluta)**, sí se añaden, pero aparecen en la carpeta raíz del freeze resultante! Y lo que quiero  es que se cree una carpeta para cada archivo. En resumen:

> Ruta del archivo en el workspace: ".\spool\Generador.py"
>
> Ruta del archivo en el compilado: ".\Generador.py"`
>
> Ruta del archivo deseada en el compilado: ".\spool\Generador.py"

Aquí mi `setup.py`:

```
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\S81335\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\S81335\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\tcl\tk8.6'
packages = ["tkinter", "cx_Oracle"]
include_files = [r"C:\Users\S81335\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs\tcl86t.dll",
                 r"C:\Users\S81335\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs\tk86t.dll",
                 r"D:\Desarrollo\python\Accesos\key.ico",
                 r"D:\Desarrollo\python\Accesos\tablas.txt",
                 r"spool/plantillalimpieza.txt",
                 r"spool/plantillactl.txt",
                 r"spool/plantillasql.txt",
                 r"spool/Generador.py",]

setup(
    name="Generador de accesos",
    description='Generador de accesos',
    version=__version__,
    options={"build_exe": {
        'packages': packages,
        'include_files': include_files,
        # 'excludes': excludes,
        'include_msvcr': True,
    }},
    executables=[Executable("Manual.py", base="Win32GUI", icon="key.ico")]
)
```

No estoy muy seguro de cómo hacer la pregunta un poco más clara, ya que leyéndola quizás es difícil de entender :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la forma. De todas formas parece que hay que incluir toda la carpeta para que se cree en la carpeta del build.

```
include_files = [r"C:\Users\S81335\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs\tcl86t.dll",
                 r"C:\Users\S81335\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs\tk86t.dll",
                 r"D:\Desarrollo\python\Accesos\key.ico",
                 r"D:\Desarrollo\python\Accesos\tablas.txt",
                 r"spool/"]
```

Estuve usando un workaround en el mismo `setup.py` que crea la carpeta y mueve los archivos una vez termina de correr la instalación, pero encontré la respuesta en [SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079268/how-can-i-include-a-folder-with-cx-freeze).